# React Native Textinput backspace won't fire if textinput value is empty in Android

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-textinput

As titled,

I need the backspace event to alter other states in the component.

```
const onKeyPressHandler = ({ nativeEvent }) => {
    if (nativeEvent.key === 'Backspace') {
        if (
            !TextInputValue.trim() &&
            otherstate.length
        ) {
            removeOtherState(otherstate[otherstate.length - 1]);
        }
    }
};
```

This code can work on IOS just fine, can trigger backspace even if textinput value becomes empty, but not on Android. The moment the `TextInputValue` becomes empty, any backspace keypress will not trigger this handler. Same goes to `onChange` and `onChangeText` too.

Is there a way to detect backspace key being pressed on the textinput even after the textinput value becomes empty on Android?